# Preformatted content with user image in Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

i am building a Wordpress theme for my company.

On the homepage, the layout features graphically complex blocks, containing an image and a text (these are the two editable contents of the block, the rest is fixed by design). The editors of this site aren't able to write HTML so i must provide them with easy options.

**What should i use to give the editor the ability to add such a block just by selecting an image and entering a text?** The them should build the block from these two pieces of data.

Ideally, i'd like that the editor could click on "add a location block" ("location" is the content type), then be prompted to enter a text, then could select an image through Worpress image dialog.

*I've been looking at "custom post type" but it doesn't seem to address my issue, as i just want some specific content to appear in a page*

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i used custom post types in a way i didn't think of.

I registered a new type of post, then i listed them in a custom loop (thanks to WP query) in a dedicated template. I didn't know you could use custom post type within other posts (pages are posts too) in the template.

It's something like that:

`functions.php` holds the post type registration:

```
function place_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Places', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Place', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Places', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Places', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'See Place', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Place', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Place', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Place', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Places', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'place_type', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Places', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail'),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'menu_icon'           => '',
        'can_export'          => false,
        'has_archive'         => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'rewrite'             => false,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'place_key', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'place_post_type', 0 );
```

Then it's easy to use it in a template:

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=-1&post_type=place_type'); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="place">
        <p class="place_image"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></p>

        <p class="place_desc">
            <span class="place_title"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?><br /></span>
            <span class="place_excerpt"><?php echo nl2br(get_the_excerpt()); ?></span>
        </p>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The only two things i still didn't figure out is how to:

- Set custom and compulsory fields in a custom post type (you can use the standard ones, or accept custom fields, but not define mandatory fields that will be required when create a post of this type).
- How to have the labels language dependant.